# Find field name that matches the passed string and set its value

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-models

In Django how can I find a field name in a model?

Here's what I mean :

```
my_field = 'message'
MyTable.objects.filter(pk=user_id).update(my_field='new message')
```

The `MyTable` model has a field named `message`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with `my_field` as the key, then use dictionary unpacking to pass it to `update()`:

```
my_field = 'message'
kwargs = {my_field: 'new message'}
MyTable.objects.filter(pk=user_id).update(**kwargs)
```